# Plot bar chart from top to bottom

Tags: highcharts, bar-chart

I need to plot the Highcharts column chart from top to bottom. Any advice?

Comment: Hi @Jerry, Could you add more details about your problem? You can refer to this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5cxL2mka/ and describe what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make use of `reversed` property in Y-Axis to plot the chart from top to bottom.

```
yAxis: {
   reversed: true,
}
```