# How to display data from top to bottom in stacked bar-chart QuickChart?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I am making a stacked bar-chart using QuickChart. The stack loads the data from bottom to top.
I want it to be top to bottom, having my first entry at the top.
Referring to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66705648/plot-bar-chart-from-top-to-bottom), I tried adding `reversed` like in Highcharts, but it doesn't help.

```
yAxis: {
   reversed: true,
}
```

[My chart](https://quickchart.io/chart/render/zf-928377c5-d482-4fb5-9703-73e68e1b7b13)

I have attached the chart output.
I need "Count of A" on top. But "Count of E" is on top.
The code for my chart seems to be irrelevant to post here, but if needed, I can add the code here.
Please see what can I add to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because quickchart by default still uses V2 and V2 syntax is different so you will need to put it like this:

```js
options: {
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        reverse: true
      }
    }]
  }
},
```

**Edit:**

Chart.js draws datasets in order the are in the datasets array by default (last to first if I remember correctly). So you would need to reorder your datasets.

You can also use the order property in the dataset to specify the draw order.
To make the legend the way it still is you can try to accomplish it using the sort callback. If that doesn't work you will need to provide a custom generateLabels function where you can give the items back in the order you want

Comment: That makes the whole chart upside down. But, I specifically want only the data to be top to bottom.
[New chart](https://quickchart.io/chart/render/zf-19840f1b-b37d-4381-bf7a-65773565ed5f)

Comment: It is crazy that this finally worked. I used the order property. Clean and simple. Have been searching for a couple of days. Thank you.
Also, I still have things to know particularly about QuickChart that aren't clear in any sources. Like, onClick function on legends, to hide/show data. Any means to communicate with you?

Comment: Don't think you can use those functions since quickchart uses chart.js but server sided so it just sends you an image of the chart instead of actually drawing the chart on a canvas. Do you loose all the event listeners chart.js attaches to the chart. So if you want those function you will have to use chart js itself instead of quickchart

Comment: I thought the same. But, got intimidated by the possibility, as the Legend section in QuickChart documentation suggested to refer to the Chart.js docs for more and never said it is not possible.